# you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page - Google maps API and JQuery autocomplete error

Tags: jquery-ui, debugging, google-maps, autocomplete, firebug

I'm using JQuery UI autocomplete to populate an address search box with suggested addressed, sourced from Google's geocoding service, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $("#address").autocomplete({
    //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
    source: function (request, response) {
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term }, function (results, status) {
        response($.map(results, function (item) {
          return {
              label: item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
              };
        }));
    });
},
//This bit is executed upon selection of an address
select: function (event, ui) {
    $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
    $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
}
});
});
```

First time I load the page, the autocomplete doesn't work and I get this error in the JavaScript console:

Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

I've checked, and I'm definitely only calling the API once (it isn't being included by any other included scripts)

Strange things is that if I put a Firebug breakpoint on the first line of the above code, I don't get the error, and the autocomplete works fine.

Any ideas what's going on?

UPDATE:  here's a fuller version of the main code for the page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     document.createElement('header'); document.createElement('nav'); document.createElement('section'); document.createElement('article'); document.createElement('aside'); document.createElement('footer'); document.createElement('banner'); document.createElement('menu'); document.createElement('hgroup'); document.createElement('figure'); document.createElement('figcaption'); document.createElement('details'); document.createElement('details');</script>
 <!-- IE 6/7/8/9 Fix Script Ends Here-->

    <link href="/css/mobile-normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/mobile-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/mobile-tradegothic-condeighteen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/mobile-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/mobile-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/scripts/mobile/retina.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/mobile/jquery.mobile-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/mobile/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // hide #back-top first
            $("#back-top").hide();

            // fade in #back-top
            $(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                        $('#back-top').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $('#back-top').fadeOut();
                    }
                });

                // scroll body to 0px on click
                $('#back-top a').click(function () {
                    $('body,html').animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 800);
                    return false;
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <section>


<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/purl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB3Qs6Lp_YmhsC85fMfjHYaT5D4X_iwXZA&sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var suppliedAddress = $.url().param("address");

        if (suppliedAddress && (suppliedAddress != "")) {
            $("#address").val($.url().param("address"));
        }

        var selectedClasses = $.url().param("classes");

        if (selectedClasses != null) {
            var arrSelectedClasses = selectedClasses.split(',');

            for (i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
                var chk = $("#filter_" + i);
                if (chk != null) {
                    if ($.inArray(chk.val(), arrSelectedClasses) > -1) {
                        chk.attr('checked', 'checked');
                    } else {
                        chk.removeAttr('checked');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        $(function () {
            $("#address").autocomplete({
                //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
                source: function (request, response) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': request.term }, function (results, status) {
                        response($.map(results, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.formatted_address,
                                value: item.formatted_address,
                                latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                                longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                            };
                        }));
                    });
                },
                //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
                    $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
                }
            });
        });

        $("form").submit(function () {
            var filter = [];
            for (i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
                var chk = $("#filter_" + i);
                if (chk != null && chk.is(':checked')) {
                    filter.push(chk.val());
                }
            }
            $("#selectedClasses").val(filter);
        });
    });

</script>
<form method="post" action="/global/en/find-a-class-list/" id="classList">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUENTM4MQ9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEQZGQWAgIDDxYCHgRUZXh0BSFQbGVhc2UgZW50ZXIgYSBsb2NhdGlvbiB0byBzZWFyY2hkZFENvCYrrddI6iYEHYyK3WKiJInatX9zdzE8+DJIH4IF" />
</div>

<div class="search_form2">
    <div class="search_field2">
        <input name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$MainContent$ClassLocatorList_1$address" type="text" id="address" class="input12" />
        <span>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="" class="retina-sprite" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_box">
        <input name="filter" type="button" value="Filter" class="filter" onclick="$('#filterpanel, #addressSearch, #clubList').toggle();" />
    </div>
    <input id="latitude" type="hidden" name="lat" />
    <input id="longitude" type="hidden" name="lon" />
</div>
    Please enter a location to search


</form>


    </section>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You asked: "Any ideas what's going on?". The code you posted doesn't event include the API once, how are we supposed to know why it is being included twice?  Possibly complete code or a link to your map, might be called for.

Comment: can you give a link to that page?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really provide a link as this is a page that's not live and is supposed to be under wraps until it's launched

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this script:

```
<script src="/scripts/mobile/jquery.mobile-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

that's included just before the Google maps API, is somehow interfering with the Google maps API, and if I include the script immediately *after* including the API, the problem goes away.  Not sure exactly why this happens, suspect it may be to do with the order that certain page elements or events are being called or bound.  Here's how the mobile menu script is called (from the main.js script that's also being included):

$("body").mobile_menu({
  menu: ['#main-nav ul', '#secondary-nav ul'],
    menu_width: 275,
    prepend_button_to: '#mobile-bar'
});

```
/* Mobile Menu jQuery Plugin
 *
 * Creates a side nav bar that mimics the native IOS nav slide drawer
 *
 * Author: Nick Brewer
 * Version: 0.5
 *
 * REQUIRES: jQuery
 */

var mobileApp = mobileApp || {};

;(function(mobileApp,$){
  function getAndroidVersion() {
    var user = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var android = user.indexOf("android") != -1;
    if (android) {
      var android2 = user.indexOf("android 2") != -1;
      var android4 = user.indexOf("android 4") != -1;
      if (android2) {
        return false;
      }
      if (android4) {
        var pointVersion = user.indexOf("android 4.") != -1;
        if (pointVersion) {
          var pVer = parseInt(user.substr(user.indexOf("android 4.") + 10, 1), 10);
          if (pVer >= 2) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }


    var goodBrowser = getAndroidVersion();
  if (!goodBrowser) {
    $("html").addClass("old-android");
  }
  var MobileMenu = function(elem, options){
    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;
  };

  MobileMenu.prototype = {
    defaults: {
      page_id: 'build-menu-page',
      menu: '', // set as an array for multiple menus
      menu_width: 260,
      menu_id: "mobile-nav",
      button_content: 'Open menu',
      prepend_button_to: '',
      menu_bar: ''
    },

    /*
     * Initiate app. Set Layout.
     *
     * @return this
     */
    init: function(){
      var _this = this;
      _this.config = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, _this.options);

      if($(_this.config.menu_id).length === 0){
        this.setLayout();
      }

      return _this;
    },

    /*
     * Clone site navigation and set it as mobile nav, set Class on each new menu
     *
     * @return false if no menu option is provided
     */

    buildMenu: function(){
      var _this = this;
      _this.config = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, _this.options);
      var menu = _this.config.menu,
          mobile_menu = $("#build-menu"),
          menu_collection = [];

      // GET MENU AND BUILD MOBILE NAV
      if(menu){
        if($.isArray(menu)){
          $(menu).each(function(i, e){
            mobile_menu.append($(e).clone().addClass(_this.config.menu_id+"-"+i));
            $(e).hide();
          });
        } else {
          mobile_menu.append($(menu).clone().addClass(_this.config.menu_id+"-0").removeAttr("id"));
          $(menu).hide();
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },

    /*
     * Set CSS for new layout.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    setCSS: function(){
      var _this = this;
      _this.config = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, _this.options);

      $("#build-menu-overlay").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        "z-index": 99,
        opacity: 0,
        display: "none"
      });

      $("html,body").css("height","100%");

      if(_this.config.menu_bar){
        if (goodBrowser) {
        $(_this.config.menu_bar).css({
            position: "fixed"
          });
        }
      else {
          $(_this.config.menu_bar).css({
            position: "absolute"
          });
        }
      }

      //$("<style />").appendTo("head").html('#'+_this.config.page_id+' { position: relative; min-height: 100% }');
      //$("style").append('html.build-menu-open #'+_this.config.page_id+' { position: fixed; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0 }');
    },

    /*
     * Set Layout, Build Menu, Set CSS. Set event handler for menu.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    setLayout: function(){
      var _this = this;
          _this.config = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, _this.options);

      // If prepend_button_to is not set to something custom, then just prepend to the page setting
      if(_this.config.prepend_button_to == ''){
        var prepend_button_to = "#"+_this.config.page_id;
      } else {
        var prepend_button_to = _this.config.prepend_button_to;
      }

      // SET HTML FRAMEWORK
      _this.$elem.wrapInner('<div id="'+_this.config.page_id+'" />').find("#"+_this.config.page_id).before('<div id="build-menu" />');
      $(prepend_button_to).prepend('<a href="#" id="build-menu-button">'+_this.config.button_content+'</a>');
      $("#"+_this.config.page_id).prepend('<div id="build-menu-overlay" />');

      this.buildMenu();
      this.setCSS();

      var element = document.getElementById(_this.config.page_id);
      element.addEventListener("oTransitionEnd", remove_animation_class,false);
      element.addEventListener("transitionend", remove_animation_class,false);
      element.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", remove_animation_class,false);
      element.addEventListener("MSTransitionEnd", remove_animation_class,false);

      function remove_animation_class(){
        if($("html").hasClass("build-menu-close")){
          $("html").removeClass("build-menu-animating");
        }
      }

      // EVENT HANDLER FOR MENU BUTTON
      $("#build-menu-button, #build-menu-overlay").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var html = $("html");
        var page = $("#"+_this.config.page_id);
        var overlay = $("#build-menu-overlay");

        html.addClass("build-menu-animating");

        if(html.hasClass("build-menu-open")){
          html.removeClass("build-menu-open");
          html.addClass("build-menu-close");

        if (goodBrowser) {
          page.css({
            "-webkit-transform": "translateX(0px)",
            "-moz-transform": "translateX(0px)",
            "-o-transform": "translateX(0px)",
            "-ms-transform": "translateX(0px)",
            "transform": "translateX(0px)"
          });
        }
      else {
          page.css("left", "0px");
        }

          overlay.fadeTo("slow",0, function(){
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
          });
        } else {
          html.addClass("build-menu-open");
          html.removeClass("build-menu-close");

      if (goodBrowser) {

        page.css({
        "-webkit-transform": "translateX("+_this.config.menu_width+"px"+")",
        "-moz-transform": "translateX("+_this.config.menu_width+"px"+")",
        "-o-transform": "translateX("+_this.config.menu_width+"px"+")",
        "-ms-transform": "translateX("+_this.config.menu_width+"px"+")",
        "transform": "translateX("+_this.config.menu_width+"px"+")"
        });

      }
      else {
      page.css("left", _this.config.menu_width+"px");
      }

          overlay.css("visibility", "visible").fadeTo("slow",0.5);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  MobileMenu.defaults = MobileMenu.prototype.defaults;

  $.fn.mobile_menu = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new MobileMenu(this, options).init();
    });
  };

  mobileApp.MobileMenu = MobileMenu;
})(mobileApp,jQuery);
```